# Resuming the permutation generation in Scala after using grouped permutation generation

Tags: scala, permutation

How to generate permutations of list using grouped method in such a way where we can save the permutations in the file after that
if we stop the program it should save the last status and
when we re run the program it can resume from where it was last.

```
list.permutations.grouped(chunkSize) foreach { x =>
    // Save chunk of permutations to file.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `drop` and `zipWithIndex` to assist with the resumption.  `drop` to skip to the specified group index. `zipWithIndex` to add indexes to the groups.

```
val start = 0 // get starting position from persistence
list.permutations.grouped(chunkSize).zipWithIndex.drop(start).foreach { case (ps, i) =>
  // persist i, the group index, and ps, the permutations
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to save the intermediate data structures that keep track of how the process is going.  You can't do that with the built-in function, but you can look at the source code to write your own permutation generator once you figure out how to extract the state (and then insert it again when you want to resume).

Standard serialization *might* work but I haven't tested it.